# How to replace parameterized string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace

My use-case is to return the redirection uri for the given uri.

URI's will be as follows:

```
/books
/books/economic-genious
/books/flight-mechanics
```

My regular expression to match the above URI's as follows:

```
/books(/(.*))?$
```

My destination is configured as follows: `/ebooks$1`. So that the above URI's will be converted to:

```
/ebooks
/ebooks/economic-genious
/ebooks/flight-mechanics
```

For this my existing Javascript code is:

```
function getMappedURI(uri) {
    var exp = new RegExp('/books(/(.*))?$');
    var destUri = '/ebooks$1';
    var redirectUri = uri.replace(exp, destUri);
    return redirectUri;
}
```

Unable to achieve the same in Python.

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?

Comment: This question is tagged Python but I can only see Javascript code... What is your Python question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a difficult way to replace the beginning of strings. If it's all about the result I would do it this way

```
import re

uri_list = [
    '/books',
    '/books/economic-genious',
    '/books/flight-mechanics',
    ]

def getMappedURI(uri):
    return re.sub(r'^\/books', '/ebooks', uri)

for uri in uri_list:
    print(getMappedURI(uri))
```

Result

```
/ebooks
/ebooks/economic-genious
/ebooks/flight-mechanics
```

If you need to use the original regular exprression this should work

```
import re

uri_list = [
    '/books/',
    '/books/economic-genious',
    '/books/flight-mechanics',
    ]

def getMappedURI(uri):
    return re.sub(r'\/books(\/(.*))?$', r'/ebooks\1', uri)

for uri in uri_list:
    print(getMappedURI(uri))
```

Result

```
/ebooks/
/ebooks/economic-genious
/ebooks/flight-mechanics
```

Note that backslashes have been added before  the slashes in your regular expression.
If you want to avoid that you must use

```
re.sub(r'/books(/(.*))?$'.replace('/', r'\/'), r'/ebooks\1', uri)
```

Comment: I have to support new python code and legacy javascript code for the existing data. Existing data is saved in the above specified format ```/books(/(.*))?$```. Is there a way to process that format ?

Comment: See the additions.